# Creating a Maven release containing multiple files & direcories

Tags: java, maven-2

How can I create a multiple files release using Maven? I.e. the release of my application need to be given as a set of directories and files within them, e.g. like a installed JBoss directory structure. How it is possible to do this with Maven? I could produce the main jar file of the application. I have to give it inside a release direcotory, within which there can be a number of other directories like the dependent libs direcotry and some application specific directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) serves this purpose. You add a `src/main/assembly` directory to your main project into which you put one or more [assembly descriptors](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html). These define what files, dependencies and project modules go into the artifact, using which filtering properties, encoding and line endings. The end result can be a zip or a compressed tar file. If you need more than one package (e.g. Windows and Linux), create multiple `assembly-*.xml files`.